# User photo disappears when I change the password

Tags: css, angular, onsubmit

I have a form where the user's photo appears. Every time I change the user password, the photo disappears from the form. I already tried to take the image of the form but it did not solve. The password change is done through onSubmit.

**HTML:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Configuração do Usuário: <b> {{userId?.name}} </b></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="example-container" style="width: 100%; margin: auto; margin-top: 2%">
      <img class="img-modal" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 60px; height: 60px;" src={{userId?.photo}}>
      <div class="example-container password-width">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Alterar a Senha" [type]="hide ? 'text' : 'password'" [(ngModel)]="senha" name="senha">
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <app-panel-config-user></app-panel-config-user>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footerButtonConfig">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm buttonConfig" *ngIf="userId?.status == 1">Desativar
      Usuário</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm buttonConfig" *ngIf="userId?.status == 0">Ativar
      Usuário</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm buttonConfig buttonColor" style="background-color: #6239BD; color: white" *ngIf="userId?.is_admin == 0">Tornar Administrador</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm buttonConfig buttonColor" style="background-color: #6239BD; color: white" *ngIf="userId?.is_admin == 1">Remover Administrador</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm buttonColor" style="background-color: #6239BD; color: white">Salvar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Code change password:**

```
onSubmit(
    userPass: UserPass,
    messageSucess: string = 'Senha alterada com Sucesso!',
    messageError: string = 'Falha ao alterar a senha.',
    action: string = '') {
    userPass.password = this.senha;
    return this.userService.putPass(this.idUser, userPass).subscribe(response => {
      if (!response) {
        console.log(Error);
      } else {
        this.userId = response;

        if (this.userId['success'] === true) {
          this.senha = '';
          this.snackBar.open(messageSucess, action, {
            duration: 4000,
            panelClass: ['success-class']
          });
        } else {
          this.snackBar.open(messageError, action, {
            duration: 4000,
            panelClass: ['error-class']
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(response)` in the beginning of your subscribe?

Comment: it returns: {success: true}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
this.userId = response;
```

You are setting the userId to the response (`{success: true}`) - but the response isn't a userId!

Remove this line, and it should work again.